# Proper usage of std::promise and std::future, segfaults

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, threadpool

I've been trying my luck on a small threadpool implementation.
However, after conceptualizing and implementing i've hit a brick wall.
I've confirmed that the worker threads ate starting up and sleeping correctly, also that they pick up and execute stored tasks correctly.
However, my program segfaults - i'm pretty sure its at `promise.set_value`.

Im not sure how i could provide a complete, verifiable example (given that i can hardly upload the whole code) but i'll include the segments
i believe to be relevant to this problem.
First off, workers are created like this:

```
worker = [this](){
    while(true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mStatusMutex); //CV for status updates
        mCV.wait(lock);
        if(mStatus != Running) //If threadpool status does not imply running
            break; //Break out of loop, ending thread in the process
        else //If threadpool is in running state
        {
            lock.unlock(); //Unlock state
            while(true) //Loop until no tasks are left
            {
                mTasksMutex.lock(); //Lock task queue
                if(mTasks.empty()) //IF no tasks left, break out of loop and return to waiting
                {
                    mTasksMutex.unlock();
                    break;
                }
                else //Else, retrieve a task, unlock the task queue and execute the task
                {
                    std::function<void()> task = mTasks.front();
                    mTasks.pop();
                    mTasksMutex.unlock();
                    task(); //Execute task
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And then started and stored into a `std::vector<std::thread>` like this:

```
std::thread tWorker(worker);
mWorkers.push_back(std::move(tWorker));
```

Now, the tricky part i believe to be the following is when adding/executing tasks to the task queue, which is a `std::queue<std::function<void()>>`.
The following two functions are relevant here:

```
template<typename RT>
inline std::future<RT> queueTask(std::function<RT()> _task, bool _execute = false)
{
    std::promise<RT> promise;
    std::function<void()> func([&_task, &promise]() -> RT {
        RT val = _task();
        promise.set_value(val);
    });

    mTasksMutex.lock();
    mTasks.emplace(func);
    mTasksMutex.unlock();
    if(_execute) flush();
    return promise.get_future();
}
inline void flush()
{
    mCV.notify_all();
}
```

Is there anything principally wrong with this approach? 
For anyone who believes this to be a bad question, feel free to tell me how i can improve it.
Full code is hosted on [my github repo](https://github.com/calcyss/cernel).

Comment: I notice you're capturing a local variable by reference and having that closure escape the scope. That could be related. I believe Clang's AddressSanitizer catches that.

Comment: _i'm pretty sure its at promise.set_value_ a debugger will tell you.

Comment: @manni66 i tried, debugging, but it wont let me step into the exact location^^

Comment: Your `std::promise` object gets destroyed as soon as the `queueTask` function exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that the promise is already dead. When `queueTask` is done, the `promise` is destroyed, and the task now just has a dangling reference. The task must share ownership of the `promise` in order for it to live long enough to fulfill it.

The same is true of the underlying `std::function` object `_task`, since you're capturing it by reference.

You're using `std::function`, which requires copyable objects, hence... `shared_ptr`:

```
template<typename RT>
inline std::future<RT> queueTask(std::function<RT()> _task, bool _execute = false)
{
    auto promise = std::make_shared<std::promise<RT>>();
    std::function<void()> func([promise, task=std::move(_task)]{
        RT val = _task();
        promise->set_value(val);
    });

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mTasksMutex); // NB: no manual lock()/unlock()!!
        mTasks.emplace(func);
    }
    if(_execute) flush();
    return promise->get_future();
}
```

Consider [`std::packaged_task`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task) instead.

Comment: Obviously, that makes sense. Thanks very much for taking your time to write this answer.